# destruct attribute from object in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-tsx

In my react application with typescript I am using `semantic-ui-react` for UI. this [snabdobx](https://codesandbox.io/s/14mx2v6jyq?module=/example.js) shows the usage of `Menu.Item` in javascript but I wan to use it in typescript and got confused.

```
<Menu.Item  name="home"  active={activeItem === 'home'}
      onClick={this.handleItemClick}>

public handleItemClick = (
    e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>,
    {name} // Here I ahve problem with typings to destruct the name
  ) => {
    this.setState({ activeItem: name });
  };
```

the types in the `MenuItem.d.ts` are

```
export interface MenuItemProps extends StrictMenuItemProps {[key: string]: any}

export interface StrictMenuItemProps {
  /*many other values */
  /** Internal name of the MenuItem. */
  name?: string

  onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>, data: MenuItemProps) => void
}
```

here `{name}:{name:string}` does not work. and geting whole data the I can not setState with `data.name`

Comment: Do `{name}:{name:string}` throws some compilation errors?

Comment: Yes it throws `Type '(e: MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>, { name }: { name: string; }) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>, data: MenuItemProps) => void'.`   @PrzemyslawPietrzak

Comment: is something wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 2):

typing like this means `({ name })` that argument `name` is `any` type, so it will not throw error.

to pass string e.g. "messages" to `handleItemClick` you should do something like this:

```js
 handleItemClick = (name: string) => () => this.setState({ activeItem: name })
...
<Menu.Item
    name='messages'
    active={activeItem === 'messages'}
    onClick={this.handleItemClick('message')}
/>
```

As you can see in TS error message, second argument of Menu.click callback is `MouseEvent` not a `{name: string}`

btw: to be more type safe you can turn on `strictFunctionTypes` flag in `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json` file

---- Edited -----

I think i got your point. Please forgot previous part:

`Menu.Item.onClick` is already typed by @types lib in `StrictMenuItemProps` interface. To get `onClick` type you can use this syntax `StrictMenuItemProps['onClick']` thats is equal to `onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>, data: MenuItemProps) => void` but you can use it without copy code form lib.

So instead typing `public handleItemClick` by `(arg1: Type1, arg2: Type2): Result { ...` you can type it by `public handleItemClick: StrictMenuItemProps['onClick'] = (e, {name}) => setState`.

TS will match function's argument types to argument so `e` and `name` will not be `any` type

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20T%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cb%3A%20(ar%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20X%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20attr%3A%20T%5B'cb'%5D%20%3D%20arg%20%3D%3E%20arg%20%2B%201%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20attr%20%3D%20arg%20%3D%3E%20arg%20%2B%201%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Comment: sorry, it is not what I am searching for, it is more like a hack. 1. why should I pass an string where it is already passed nested in data. 2.I was searching for the type of the name as getting destruct 3.it is not the approach which the official docs says

Comment: Also I think you did not read my comment reagarding the compiler error correctly that you have mentioned "`second argument of Menu.click callback is MouseEvent not a {name: string}`

Comment: I think i understand you now, please check edited part

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi is this a solution that you're looking for?

Comment: Actually before you send the edited version of the answer I figured it out and posted as answer, but your approach looks nice to yet had not time to test it and check if that is more beneficial or not but thanks for it, in few days got back to that project will test and accept your answer if it sounded more convenient

Answer (score 0):

so it seems it does not matter that the name it self is of type `string` the whole object is of type `MenuItemProps`

therefore the following solved the issue

```
  public handleItemClick = (
    e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>,
    { name }: MenuItemProps
  ) => {
    this.setState({ activeItem: name! });
  };
```